# Load the Google File picker in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I would like to load the [Google File picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/).
I have included the [JS API script](http://www.google.com/jsapi) in my extension (I include it directly in the package).

When I try to load the picker:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
          var picker, view;
          view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
          view.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.unishared.document");
          picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().setAppId(...").addView(view).setCallback(function() {}).build();
          return picker.setVisible(true);
        });
google.load('picker', '1');
```

It redirects to a blank page, with no critical error logged in the console.
Is it possible to load this API in this context?

Comment: Google JSAPI is not designed to run on extension environment (which chrome.* API is available). There are some restrictions defined by [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) in extension environment that makes chrome run extension safer. Google JSAPI should run on a normal web page environment (which is similar normal web pages, and chrome.* API is not available). There is [sandboxed pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#sandbox) introduced by chrome, let give it a try.