# Include Google Drive Picker in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am trying to include a Google Drive Picker in a chrome extension. I followed this guide to build the chromes extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

And this guide to build the picker:
https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

I used `.setOrigin()` to set the origin to the URL of the chrome extension. However the target origin provided remains https://docs.google.com and I get the following error:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:80 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': 
The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('chrome-extension://<EXTENSION ID>').
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Including more of your code will probably help making it answerable.

Comment: Finally managed to include the filepicker after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161695/load-the-google-file-picker-in-a-chrome-extension) post. I created another site for the sole purpose of displaying the file picker and included that in a sandboxed iframe.